# Can a phrase be a subject?

Tags: articles, subjects

I have the following sentence.

> In the reconstruction, *setting a stable parameter* matching with
>   entire scene is hard to achieve.

According to my understanding, the subject is '*setting a stable parameter*'. Do you think it is possible to use a phrase as a subject instead of one single word? Is my sentence correct?

Comment: It's hard to tell, but I suspect you mean 'scenario' instead of 'scene.'  A scene is a place, a scenario is a (real or imagined) situation or set of circumstances.

Comment: It's possibly referring to a "scene" in video game making; for instance, flash uses that term, I believe, in which case, a "scene" is a single game screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, absolutely!

There are a couple minor mistakes you have made other than that, though.

For instance, I would write "In the reconstruction, setting a stable parameter that matches the entire scene is hard to achieve." or "an entire scene".

Also, you mean "understanding" and not "undemanding".

You have the right idea!

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is how *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* suggests we analyze your sentence:

The subject is a non-finite subordinate clause, *setting a stable parameter matching with entire scene*.  It's marked as subordinate by having no overt subject and by having the verb in gerund-participle form (*-ing* form), which is a non-finite form.  Gerund-participial clauses commonly function as subjects.

(CGEL doesn't distinguish between the gerund and participle uses of the *-ing* form.  More traditionally, we could say this is the *gerund* form of the verb; *gerund* is a term from traditional grammar that refers to the form of a verb that can appear where a noun is expected.)

You can't generalize that "phrases can be subjects".  It's true that some phrases can.  But we can see that it's not always true; for example, preposition phrases are generally not able to function as subjects.

The subject of your sentence is fine.  However, *entire scene* needs an article: I'd write *the entire scene*.